# pass $_FILES through 2 forms

Tags: php, html

I recived files with $_FILES and want to send it again with another form.
How can I set the value of a `<input type="file">` to the files from the other form?

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="generate.php">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Select video<br></label>
<?php
    $filePath = $_FILES["video"]["tmp_name"];
    $y= 1;
    foreach($filePath as $filePath){
        echo '<input type="text" name="title[]" placeholder="Name '.$y.'" id="title" value=""><br>';
        $y++;
    }
    echo <input type="file" name="video[]" accept="video/*" multiple="" class="form-control" value="$_FILES[video][]" required>
?>
```

Comment: You can't. If a file is selected on the first form, then it should be submitted to the server for processing rather than simply passed to another form,

Comment: On the Second Form You can *reference* the file once it's been uploaded to your server, but you can't reference the file itself from the users device.

Comment: Cant be done. When the script that first received the file is finished the temporary file (the one referenced by `$_FILES`) will automatically be removed. The first script would have to move the temp file somewhere for the second script to be able to do anything with it

Comment: What's the purpose of the other form? Do you want to display a thumbnail of the uploaded file? If so it has to be uploaded/moved first.